# If $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously partially differentiable, then $f$ is (totally) differentiable. Why can one write $f_i$ as a sum?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, vector-analysis

Statement: If $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously partially differentiable, then $f$ is (totally) differentiable. $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set.

Proof:
Let $a\in U$, then $U{\epsilon}(a)\subset U$ for an $\epsilon >0$.
For $x\in U{\epsilon}(a)$ the following is true:
$$f_i(x)-f_i(a)=f_i\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ \vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}-f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\ \vdots \\a_n \end{pmatrix}\overset{?}{=}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\x_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}-f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\a_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}$$

Why can one write $f_i(x)$ as a sum?

### Edit after reading the comments

I tried, but $$j=1\Rightarrow f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{0}\\x_1\\x_{2}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}$$
made no sense.

I think I misunderstood the notation. It probably means:
$$j=1\Rightarrow f_i\begin{pmatrix}  x_1 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}- f_i\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\x_2 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}\\
j=2\Rightarrow f_i\begin{pmatrix}  a_1\\x_2 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}- f_i\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\x_3 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}\\
j=3\Rightarrow f_i\begin{pmatrix}  a_1\\a_2\\x_3 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}- f_i\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\x_4 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}\\
\Rightarrow \sum \limits_{j=1}^{3} f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\x_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}-f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\a_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}= f_i\begin{pmatrix}  x_1 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}- f_i\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\x_4 \\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}$$

So it is indeed a telescopic sum - thank you :)

Comment: It's just a telescoping sum. It's only algebra and it has nothing to do with differentiability.

Comment: Try to write that sum for the $n=3$ case and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit to my question. I'm only unsure about the case $n=j$: $$j=n\Rightarrow f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\a_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}= f_i\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\a_n \end{pmatrix}$$ Is $f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\x_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}$ definded as zero for j=n: $$f_i\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\\vdots\\a_{j-1}\\x_j\\x_{j+1}\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}:=0$$